# DEP0700: Registration of the app failed. While UWP extension launch Consult app(.NET framework)

Tags: uwp, console-application, registration, sideloading

When using UWP extension to open Consult app(.NET framework) will get (Error    DEP0700: Registration of the app failed. [0x80073CF6] AppxManifest.xml(33，10): Error  0x80080204: Registration failed:  b0b2f355-4232-447c-890a-feec3ec7ad4c_1.0.0.0_x86__hbnhee7zt39k0 package，because can't not find EntryPoint or StartPage )

in visual studio 2019.
in Windows10.

Using FullTrustProcessLauncher to lunch other app

```cs
protected async override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
   base.OnNavigatedTo(e);

   if (ApiInformation.IsApiContractPresent("Windows.ApplicationModel.FullTrustAppContract", 1, 0))
   {
       await FullTrustProcessLauncher.LaunchFullTrustProcessForCurrentAppAsync();
   }
}
```

Cousule app start here

```cs
namespace CollectDataAP
{
    class Program
    {
        static private AppServiceConnection connection = null;

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.ReadLine();

            InitializeWMIHandler();
            InitGlobalVariable();

            string tempForUWP = "", tempForOutput = "";
```

For side loading in Windows Application package project

```xml
 
      <Extensions>
        <uap:Extension Category="windows.appService">
            <uap:AppService Name="SampleInteropService" />
        </uap:Extension>
        <desktop:Extension Category="windows.fullTrustProcess" Executable="CollectDataAP\CollectDataAP.exe" />
      </Extensions>
```

File structure

[image]

When I redo this this UWP project and just only side-loading Console App. it can normally run.
Can give me some direction?

Comment: From the information and code snippets provided so far, I tested it and there was no problem. Could you please share a minimal project that reproduces your problem to help us further check the problem for you?

Comment: @JunjieZhu-MSFT Zhu I had been sove this problem. The error reason is system lanuch anther project not UWP. So, just commend  `await FullTrustProcessLauncher.LaunchFullTrustProcessForCurrentAppAsync();` and others code which can be launched anther project, make Waproj only launch UWP. and uncommend modifyed code.

Answer (score 0):

Just commend
in Package.appxmanifest

```cs
<Extensions>
    <uap:Extension Category="windows.appService">
        <uap:AppService Name="SampleInteropService" />
    </uap:Extension>
  <desktop:Extension Category="windows.fullTrustProcess" Executable="CollectDataAP\CollectDataAP.exe" />
</Extensions>
```

[Remove all project except UWP](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IWVfZ.png)

commend `await FullTrustProcessLauncher.LaunchFullTrustProcessForCurrentAppAsync();`

And compiler, only show UWP.

Than revert to original can sove this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Move all app and compile. Than, link UWP and compile. Than, link sideload app and compile.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LHicz.png)